# Create Polygon / MultiLineString from linestrings based on their id

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, postgis

I have two tables like this:

```
lines:
line_id|    geometry
-------------------
1      |    ....
2      |    ....
3      |    ....
4      |    ....
5      |    ....
6      |    ....
```

(The geometry column is filled up in the lines table)

```
polygons:
    poly_id |    line_id 
    --------------------
    1       |       1     
    1       |       2     
    1       |       3        
    1       |       4        
    2       |       3       
    2       |       5      
    2       |       6        
    2       |       7
```

As you can see in the polygon table I have the *line_id*-s of the lines that makes up a polygon.
What I do is, I make a new table with only one record per *poly_id*:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(poly_id) 
INTO polygons_new
FROM polygons;

SELECT AddGeometryColumn('polygons_new','geom',23700,'POLYGON',2);
```

After this, I would like to fill up the *geom* column, but so far I couldn't accomplish this.
What I've tried is something like this:

```
UPDATE polygons_new
SET geom = (SELECT ST_Collect(SELECT geometry FROM lines as a, polygons as b WHERE a.line_id = b.line_id))
```

The problem with this is that it returns more than one row in the subquery.
Is there a way to do this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using, [`ST_Collect`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html), [`ST_MergeLine`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) and then create the polygon using [`ST_MakePolygon`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html)? The following example will give you an idea of what I am talking about:

```
WITH j (id,geom) AS (
  VALUES (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(30 10, 10 30)'),
         (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(10 30, 40 40)'),
         (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(40 40, 30 10)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(50 60, 60 20)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(60 20, 45 45)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(45 45, 50 60)')
) 
 SELECT 
  ST_MakePolygon(
    ST_LineMerge(
      ST_Collect(geom))) 
FROM j
GROUP BY id
```

[image]

**EDIT:** In case only a `MULTILINESTRING`suffices, just use `ST_Collect` (see comments):

```
WITH j (id,geom) AS (
  VALUES (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(30 10, 10 30)'),
         (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(10 30, 40 40)'),
         (1,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(40 40, 30 10)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(50 60, 60 20)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(60 20, 45 45)'),
         (2,'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(45 45, 50 60)')
) 
SELECT ST_Collect(geom)
FROM j
GROUP BY id;
```

[image]

Comment: No, I haven't tried it before. Actually ST_Collect is enough for me, and you gave me a good idea with the GROUP BY part. I haven't thought of something simple as this.
In the end, what worked for me is:
`SELECT poly_id, ST_Collect FROM lines AS a polygons AS b WHERE a.line_id = b.line_id GROUP BY b.poly_id`

Comment: Thanks! At first I thought I needed a `POLYGON`, but it turned out `MULTILINESTRING` is sufficent for me.